# Dart KeyboardEvent Backspace

Tags: keyboard, dart, keyevent

I use this code:

```dart
window.onKeyPress.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
  print(e.charCode.toString() + " " + new String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
});
```

Which prints out basically everything, except <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. So, how to manage <kbd>Backspace</kbd> press?

Comment: It does not trigger the input method at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `keydown` event instead.

`KeyPress` event is invoked only for character (printable) keys, `KeyDown` event is raised for all including non-printable such as <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>, etc.

Comment: However, there seems to be a problem. Every char's code is now 0.

Comment: You have to use both events. For printable characters use `on-kepress` and `e.charCode` for non-printable use `on-keydown` and `e.keyCode` (tab has 8). `charCode` is only for printable keys.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer How can i implement with flutter basically i want ```BackSpace``` event.